# Get real time Pusherjs connection state via Laravel Echo in Nuxtjs

Tags: laravel-echo, pusher-js, nuxtjs

I want to check the connection state of `Pusherjs` from `$echo` in NuxtJs page.

when I use:

```
mounted(){
   this.connection = this.$echo.connector.pusher.connection.state;
}
```

It works but it only set the initial connection status which is `connecting` and it's static.

But when I use:

```
computed:{
   connection: this.$echo.connector.pusher.connection.state
}
```

It returns error:

```
TypeError
Cannot read property '$echo' of undefined
```

So how can I be notified about connection status real time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
this.$echo.connector.pusher.connection.bind("state_change", (states) => {
   // states = {previous: 'oldState', current: 'newState'}
});
```

Reference:
https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/connection#binding-to-all-state-changes